# Eclipse IDE Setup for PHP/Zend, Javascript/JQuery, CSS, HTML, XML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, eclipse, html

I would like to setup my Eclipse IDE (Helios 3.6.x) for Web Development and I have been trying to do this for hours now without satisfying results. I was using Eclipse with the Aptana 1.5.x Plugin until now, but it is outdated, painfully slow, has no support for XHTML 1.0 / HTML 5 and CSS 3 and it is not supported any more. Aptana 3.0.0 instead is very buggy and not ready to use.

So I try to set up Eclipse for PHP Developers to get the IDE I need, but there are a lot of problems. The PHP support is good enough: Code completion, errors are detected and highlighted detailed, auto-code-completion and documentation on key up, code outline and custom syntax highlighting. But I can not get working the same things for Javascript / JQuery, HTML and CSS files, errors are shown not or poorly. I tried Eclipse for Javascript Developers, things are are better here with HTML and Javascript (Errors, but no autocompletion), CSS still sucks.

I tried some plugins searching on the internet but nothing seems really to work and most plugins are outdated, too. Does anybody know the right and up to date plugins for this purpose? Or is it just a problem with the settings and I am not able to figure out how to configure it? How can I integrate Eclipse for PHP Developers and Eclipse for Javascript Developers into one installation?

I cannot imagine to be the first one to have this problem, this is such a standard IDE setup for Web Development.

Comment: what is wrong with the currently stable aptana2? work really nice in most cases...

Comment: Aptana 2 does not have PHP support (big fail, i think)

Answer (score 2):

Install Eclipse for PHP Developers (PDT) and then install aptana studio v2 as a plug-in. That way you have the autocompletion for php and all the nifty features of aptana for other web-related files such as javascript (then you can actually install support for specific libraries such as jquery).

Comment: This idea actually is not so bad, I wonder why I have not tried this. It is not a perfect solution though, because there are always some extra clicks. It works for me now, but I am still waiting for a better solution.

Comment: I've been looking for years a better answer than this, and so far it is the best thing I've found. I think one of the big disadvantages of aptana is the lack of support of "Go to Definition" function in external files. Other than that, it sort of gets the job done. They also have decent customer support.